# Django FileBrowser-No-Grappelli images not loading

Tags: python, django, django-filebrowser

Ive installed django [file-browser-no-grappelli](https://github.com/smacker/django-filebrowser-no-grappelli)

I can use it in the backend but the images don't come through i get a 404 error.

/media/uploads/products/el45bg_admin_thumbnail.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2608

settings ive added to my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
DIRECTORY = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media' 'uploads')
FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_THUMBNAIL = 'admin_thumbnail'
FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_VERSIONS = ['thumbnail', 'small', 'medium', 'big', 'large']
VERSIONS_BASEDIR = "versions"
```

The directories are created and i can create more directories through the admin interface and upload files which get resized.

So what im wondering is why wont the images appear? as ive done everything the guides on readthedocs states.

Comment: Could it be an access problem? You can *upload* images to that directory, but you can then not *download* them? Maybe you need to put the images to access in another directory (e.g. under /static).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I needed to add

- static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) to my urls.py